# Go lang - Get current mouse cursor position with RobotGo

Tags: go, ide, position, mouse

I'm a beginner in Go and I want to solve a small task: to print the current coordinates of the mouse cursor to the console and update them if the mouse moves. For this, I took the library robotgo, downloaded it using "**go get github.com/go-vgo/robotgo**", then "**go get -u github.com/go-vgo/robotgo**", and imported it using import "**github.com/go-vgo/robotgo**". Here's the code I wrote:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/go-vgo/robotgo"
)

func main() {
    for {
        x, y := robotgo.GetMousePos()
        fmt.Printf("Current position X=%d, Y=%d", x, y)
        if x == 540 && y == 960 {
            fmt.Println("Cursor @center")
        }

        robotgo.Move(x, y)
    }
}
```

But I'm getting errors:

```
# github.com/robotn/gohook
C:\CODING\SDK\GO-PATH\pkg\mod\github.com\robotn\gohook@v0.40.0\event.go:51:10: undefined: addEvent
C:\CODING\SDK\GO-PATH\pkg\mod\github.com\robotn\gohook@v0.40.0\event.go:62:7: undefined: Start
C:\CODING\SDK\GO-PATH\pkg\mod\github.com\robotn\gohook@v0.40.0\event.go:75:18: undefined: KeyHold
C:\CODING\SDK\GO-PATH\pkg\mod\github.com\robotn\gohook@v0.40.0\event.go:83:18: undefined: KeyUp
C:\CODING\SDK\GO-PATH\pkg\mod\github.com\robotn\gohook@v0.40.0\event.go:95:22: undefined: KeyUp
C:\CODING\SDK\GO-PATH\pkg\mod\github.com\robotn\gohook@v0.40.0\event.go:96:4: undefined: End
C:\CODING\SDK\GO-PATH\pkg\mod\github.com\robotn\gohook@v0.40.0\event.go:113:7: undefined: Start
C:\CODING\SDK\GO-PATH\pkg\mod\github.com\robotn\gohook@v0.40.0\event.go:121:17: undefined: MouseMove
C:\CODING\SDK\GO-PATH\pkg\mod\github.com\robotn\gohook@v0.40.0\event.go:128:22: undefined: MouseDown
C:\CODING\SDK\GO-PATH\pkg\mod\github.com\robotn\gohook@v0.40.0\event.go:129:4: undefined: End
C:\CODING\SDK\GO-PATH\pkg\mod\github.com\robotn\gohook@v0.40.0\event.go:129:4: too many errors
```

**UPD 16.03.2023 problem was solved by completely removing the library and its dependencies, and then reinstalling it.**

Comment: If your system is windows then you can use winapi ([GetCursorPos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcursorpos)) to do it; no need to rely on other third-party libraries.

Comment: @Carson it's cool, but how i will use it in Go?

Answer (score 1):

For windows, use the system API :[GetCursorPos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcursorpos)

```golang
//go:build windows

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    userDll := syscall.NewLazyDLL("user32.dll")
    getWindowRectProc := userDll.NewProc("GetCursorPos")
    type POINT struct {
        X, Y int32
    }
    var pt POINT
    _, _, eno := syscall.SyscallN(getWindowRectProc.Addr(), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&pt)))
    if eno != 0 {
        fmt.Println(eno)
    }
    fmt.Printf("[cursor.Pos] X:%d Y:%d\n", pt.X, pt.Y)
}
```

Comment: The above example may be boring, but if you want to learn more about the usage of WinAPI, you can refer to an [example](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/go-pkg/blob/d455304d0fc5b28399f5f9a0bcc72a630a22f193/v2/w32/gdi32_func_test.go#L568-L709) project of mine. In this example, clicking the left mouse button will print out the color of the mouse position, and pressing the right mouse button will terminate the program. You don't necessarily have to import the project, but by looking at the definitions, you can understand how Go communicates with the Windows API.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this Windows solution! I created two files that are platform specific. util_windows.go and util_unix.go

in util_windows.go the first line I have this.
//go:build windows
// +build windows

in the other I have that
//go:build !windows
// +build !windows